# Broadcast pandas.Series.div column-wise to a DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, broadcast, apply

I have an operation that works fine, but is generating a:

```
FutureWarning: TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by default 
is deprecated.
```

So I'd like to do the calculation in a way that is coherent with future versions.

I have a `pandas.Series` and I'd like to divide that `Series` by each column of a `pandas.DataFrame`.

So let's say I have and `Series`, and a `DataFrame`, with the following shapes:

```
In [15]: my_series.shape
Out[15]: (1504,)

In [16]: my_df.shape
Out[16]: (1504, 4)
```

When I run `my_series/my_df` I get the desired result:

```
In [17]: (my_series/my_df).shape
Out[17]: (1504, 4)
```

Of course, implementing the `pandas.Series.divide` operator comes back with an error:

```
In [18]: my_series.div(my_df)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1504) (1504,4)
```

I've given the `series.apply` functionality a try, but haven't gotten what I expect (based on how I use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`):

```
In [19]: my_series.apply(pandas.Series.divide, my_df)
Out[19]: ValueError       

In [22]: my_series.apply(pandas.Series.divide, lambda x: my_df[my_df.columns[x]])
Out[22]: TypeError
```

Any insight, as always, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't think of doing it this way... **quite** embarrassing really.

```
 In [24]: my_df.apply(lambda x: my_series.div(x)).shape
 Out[24]: (1504, 4)
```